# Uncheck checkcolumn in Extjs4 Grid

Tags: css, grid, extjs4

Functionality is that there is a popup window which contains selected rows of base grid: Base grid contains checkcolumn as follows:

```
{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        text: 'Select',
        dataIndex: 'active',
        itemId: 'checkcolumnId',
        width: 55
     }
```

Controller which is evoked when checkbox is checked or unchecked:

```
'#checkcolumnId' : {
        checkchange : function(column, recordIndex, checked) {
          if(checked){
            var rec = statusStore.getAt(recordIndex);
            reassignStore.add(rec);
          }else if(statusStore.getAt(recordIndex)!=null){
            var indexNumber = reassignStore.findExact('taskId', statusStore.getAt(recordIndex).data.taskId, 0);
            reassignStore.removeAt(indexNumber);
          }
          return false;
        }
     }
```

reassign store is the store for popup which displays selected (checked) records of base grid.

When I am checking the checkbox of a row in base grid I can see that that records shows up in reassign grid but the issue is when I click the checkbox (checkcolumn of base grid) again it dont display unchecked, though it performs uncheck operation ie it goes to false condition of checkchange method above.

This functionality is available at ext-4.0.7-gpl/examples/grid/row-editing.html 
Using chrome debugger I found that when I try to uncheck the row in base grid it does not call renderer method of CheckColumn.js which is responsible for changing css of checked column.

CheckColumn.js

```
renderer : function(value){
        var cssPrefix = Ext.baseCSSPrefix, cls = [cssPrefix + 'grid-checkheader'];
        if (value) {
            cls.push(cssPrefix + 'grid-checkheader-checked');
        }
        return '<div class="' + cls.join(' ') + '">&#160;</div>';
    }
```

If I comment reassignStore.add(rec); or reassignStore.removeAt(indexNumber); line of checkChange method I am able to uncheck properly ( ie with css applied so I can visually see unchecked box)

Is this a bug ? Why I am not seeing css applied when I uncheck ?

Answer (score 1):

What's the data type of this column containing checkboxes? If it is other than boolean, there might be such a problem. Because in ***CheckColumn.js***, there is a statement like:

```
checked = !record.get(dataIndex);
```

So if `record.get(dataIndex) == false`, checked should be true, but for example, `record.get(dataIndex) == "false"`, checked would be false still. In that case, renderer is never called.